Complex BigQuery recursive CTE use case that joins on non-unique key and also unions at the same time
I have a complex (but highly interesting!) use case for BigQuery recursive CTE. I understand how to solve it conceptually but after hours of trying, I just can't get my head around exactly how to do it - I've made no progress. I'm not even clear if it's a join or a union + window function problem. Thanks in advance for any complete solutions or just pointers.
A simplified excerpt of my source data looks like the following (WITH statement is at the bottom for ease of copying):



date
region_number
region_name
channel
subchannel
activity_type
region_name_baseline
conversions




2024-06-01
1
Control




8


2024-06-02
1
Control




6


2024-06-03
1
Control




7


2024-06-04
1
ITVX
tv
bvod
itvx
Control
11


2024-06-05
1
ITVX
tv
bvod
itvx
Control
13


2024-06-06
1
ITVX
tv
bvod
itvx
Control
13


2024-06-07
1
ITVX + TikTok
paid_social
tiktok

ITVX
18


2024-06-08
1
ITVX + TikTok
paid_social
tiktok

ITVX
18


2024-06-09
1
ITVX + TikTok
paid_social
tiktok

ITVX
22



I am effectively trying to calculate incremental differences in numbers ("conversions") based on some opinionated business rules (which I describe below). I want to produce the following - which I'm pasting as an image so you can see the expected iterations - 1 per colour.

The rules for the iteration are as follows, starting with rows that have NULL region_name_baseline:

Join cte.region_name_baseline = data.region_name

If the rows that we have joined to do not have a channel value (i.e. NULL), union just the new rows. If the rows that we have joined to do have a channel value (this will happen on the 2nd iteration), we need 2 sets of new rows - 1 set should be the number of rows that were joined, with most of the values from the new data except the channel, subchannel and activity_type from the joined rows - the 2nd set should just be the unaltered new set. In the 2nd iteration of this example case, there would be 6 new rows, not just 3 new rows. But it could have been 9 new rows (6 + 3) if it had joined to 6 existing rows.

Calculating average_baseline_conversions & incremental_conversions. 3 scenarios:
i) If the parent didn't have a channel classification:
average_baseline_conversions = the average of the parent's conversions whose date was before the row in question's date.
incremental_conversions = the difference between conversions and average_baseline_conversions.
ii) If the parent did have a channel classification and we are in the "inherited set", then:
average_baseline_conversions = the average of the parent's parent's conversions whose date was before the row in question's date (we can't copy the numbers - we should rather run the same calculation but based on the rows indicated by the parent's parent).
incremental_conversions = the average of the parent's incremental_conversions.
iii) If the parent did have a channel classification and we are in the other set, then:
average_baseline_conversions = average of the parent's conversions whose date was before the row in question's date.
incremental_conversions = the difference between conversions and average_baseline_conversions. Scenario 1 and 3 are in the fact the same, just relative to their own parents.


There are plenty of edge cases with this - I'm showing a simplified excerpt but the formula in the below image are exactly, semantically correct. Some of the references could coincidentally have been other references but these are the correct calculations that I would need to reproduce in SQL:

If you dry run the logic or check the numbers, you can see how this makes sense. In the first image, there are a total of 116 conversions but if only Control had ran and performance had been consistent, we should have expected AVERAGE(6, 7, 8) * 9 = 63. The difference is 53 which is the total of incremental_conversions. The complexity is that incremental_conversions is nicely split at the row-level by the constituent parts.
WITH RECURSIVE `data` AS (
  SELECT '2024-06-01' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'Control' AS `region_name`, NULL AS `channel`, NULL AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, NULL AS `region_name_baseline`, 8 AS `conversions`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-06-02' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'Control' AS `region_name`, NULL AS `channel`, NULL AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, NULL AS `region_name_baseline`, 6 AS `conversions`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-06-03' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'Control' AS `region_name`, NULL AS `channel`, NULL AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, NULL AS 
`region_name_baseline`, 7 AS `conversions`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-06-04' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name`, 'tv' AS `channel`, 'bvod' AS `subchannel`, 'itvx' AS `activity_type`, 'Control' AS `region_name_baseline`, 11 AS `conversions`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-06-05' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name`, 'tv' AS `channel`, 'bvod' AS `subchannel`, 'itvx' AS `activity_type`, 'Control' AS `region_name_baseline`, 13 AS `conversions`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-06-06' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name`, 'tv' AS `channel`, 'bvod' AS `subchannel`, 'itvx' AS `activity_type`, 'Control' AS 
`region_name_baseline`, 13 AS `conversions`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-06-07' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX + TikTok' AS `region_name`, 'paid_social' AS `channel`, 'tiktok' AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name_baseline`, 18 AS `conversions`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-06-08' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX + TikTok' AS `region_name`, 'paid_social' AS `channel`, 'tiktok' AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name_baseline`, 18 AS `conversions`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-06-09' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX + TikTok' AS `region_name`, 'paid_social' AS `channel`, 'tiktok' AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name_baseline`, 22 AS `conversions`
)

For what it's worth, I don't have a problem with any of the calculations, I think my mental block is fundamentally around the recursive union/deliberate explosion of some rows. If I can get some pointers with this, I think I can compute all of the calculations with window functions at the very end. I "simply" just need to get, in this sample data case, from the 9 rows to 12 rows with the right attribute details filled in as per the screenshots.
EDIT
I've come up with a solution that gets me the rows I need but it's pretty nuts. There are 3 fundamental limitations/design choices of recursive CTEs in BigQuery that I'm coming up against:

Sub-queries aren't allowed. My join key is not unique and so this creates a fundamental problem as I am forced to explode out and deal with it later - which then has a recursive impact.
Window/analytic functions aren't allowed. Related to the above, I'm forced to carry through the near-cartesian join implication.
An additional union is not allowed. I really want to be able to say the following for my recursive cte definition; "seed data" + "some recursive join" + "current set of data".

To get around 3, I pre-explode the data.
To get around 1 & 2, I use a window function at the very end.
It's pretty nasty - I'd love to know if there's a better solution but here's what I have so far:
WITH RECURSIVE `data` AS (
  SELECT '2024-06-01' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'Control' AS `region_name`, NULL AS `channel`, NULL AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, NULL AS `region_name_baseline`, 8 AS `conversions`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-06-02' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'Control' AS `region_name`, NULL AS `channel`, NULL AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, NULL AS `region_name_baseline`, 6 AS `conversions`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-06-03' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'Control' AS `region_name`, NULL AS `channel`, NULL AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, NULL AS 
`region_name_baseline`, 7 AS `conversions`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-06-04' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name`, 'tv' AS `channel`, 'bvod' AS `subchannel`, 'itvx' AS `activity_type`, 'Control' AS `region_name_baseline`, 11 AS `conversions`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-06-05' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name`, 'tv' AS `channel`, 'bvod' AS `subchannel`, 'itvx' AS `activity_type`, 'Control' AS `region_name_baseline`, 13 AS `conversions`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-06-06' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name`, 'tv' AS `channel`, 'bvod' AS `subchannel`, 'itvx' AS `activity_type`, 'Control' AS 
`region_name_baseline`, 13 AS `conversions`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-06-07' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX + TikTok' AS `region_name`, 'paid_social' AS `channel`, 'tiktok' AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name_baseline`, 18 AS `conversions`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-06-08' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX + TikTok' AS `region_name`, 'paid_social' AS `channel`, 'tiktok' AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name_baseline`, 18 AS `conversions`
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2024-06-09' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX + TikTok' AS `region_name`, 'paid_social' AS `channel`, 'tiktok' AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name_baseline`, 22 AS `conversions`
),

cte_data` AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    TRUE AS `original`
  FROM `data`

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
    *,
    FALSE AS `original`
  FROM `data`
  WHERE `region_name_baseline` IS NOT NULL
),

`cte` AS (
  SELECT 
    `date`,
    `region_number`,
    `region_name`,
    `channel`,
    `subchannel`,
    `activity_type`,
    `region_name_baseline`,
    `conversions`,
    NULL AS `average_baseline_conversions`,
    NULL AS `incremental_conversions`, 
    1 AS `iteration`
  FROM `cte_data`
  WHERE `region_name_baseline` IS NULL

  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT
    `cte_data`.`date`,
    `cte_data`.`region_number`,
    `cte_data`.`region_name`,
    IF(`cte_data`.`original`, `cte`.`channel`, `cte_data`.`channel`) AS `channel`,
    IF(`cte_data`.`original`, `cte`.`subchannel`, `cte_data`.`subchannel`) AS `subchannel`,
    IF(`cte_data`.`original`, `cte`.`activity_type`, `cte_data`.`activity_type`) AS `activity_type`,
    IF(`cte_data`.`original`, `cte`.`region_name_baseline`, `cte_data`.`region_name_baseline`) AS `region_name_baseline`,
    `cte_data`.`conversions`,
    NULL AS `average_baseline_conversions`,
    NULL AS `incremental_conversions`, 
    `iteration` + 1 AS `iteration`
  FROM `cte_data`
  JOIN `cte`
    ON `cte_data`.`region_name_baseline` = `cte`.`region_name`
    AND `cte_data`.`date` > `cte`.`date`
  WHERE `cte`.`channel` IS NOT NULL OR NOT `cte_data`.`original`
)

SELECT *
FROM `cte`
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
  `region_number`, 
  `region_name_baseline`,
  `date`
) = 1
ORDER BY `iteration`, `region_number`, `region_name_baseline`, `date`

Produces:


Wow. Ok, so this turned out to be extremely non-trivial but I came up with a solution. I really hope this can be improved on but this is as elegant as I can come up with right now.
The below SQL includes some expanded complexity test data so I could verify the logic is sound amongst edge cases. In my case:

Additional level of iteration (to improve confidence there aren't bugs beyond minimal recursion)
Separate control region which should influence region 3 but not region 1 - this tests the 2nd business logic rule described in my original post

I've added some small comments below but it's still pretty difficult to get your head around. It turns out that you are not allowed to aggregate or use analytic functions or use sub-queries within recursive CTEs (they are nowhere near as powerful as I had hoped - they really only solve very basic iterative use cases). BigQuery additionally doesn't allow you to nest analytic functions. The result of all of this is some data preparation is required, CTEs are required in the middle to perform the de-duplication and business logic manipulation that would ideally be achieved more succinctly in 1 set of window functions, and an additional round of recursion is required at the end (thankfully a lot more simple).
WITH RECURSIVE `data` AS (
    SELECT '2024-06-01' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'Control' AS `region_name`, NULL AS `channel`, NULL AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, NULL AS `region_name_baseline`, 8 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-02' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'Control' AS `region_name`, NULL AS `channel`, NULL AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, NULL AS `region_name_baseline`, 6 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-03' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'Control' AS `region_name`, NULL AS `channel`, NULL AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, NULL AS `region_name_baseline`, 7 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-04' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name`, 'tv' AS `channel`, 'bvod' AS `subchannel`, 'itvx' AS `activity_type`, 'Control' AS `region_name_baseline`, 11 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-05' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name`, 'tv' AS `channel`, 'bvod' AS `subchannel`, 'itvx' AS `activity_type`, 'Control' AS `region_name_baseline`, 13 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-06' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name`, 'tv' AS `channel`, 'bvod' AS `subchannel`, 'itvx' AS `activity_type`, 'Control' AS `region_name_baseline`, 13 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-07' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX + TikTok' AS `region_name`, 'paid_social' AS `channel`, 'tiktok' AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name_baseline`, 18 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-08' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX + TikTok' AS `region_name`, 'paid_social' AS `channel`, 'tiktok' AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name_baseline`, 18 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-09' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX + TikTok' AS `region_name`, 'paid_social' AS `channel`, 'tiktok' AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, 'ITVX' AS `region_name_baseline`, 22 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-01' AS `date`, 2 AS `region_number`, 'Control' AS `region_name`, NULL AS `channel`, NULL AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, NULL AS `region_name_baseline`, 5 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-02' AS `date`, 2 AS `region_number`, 'Control' AS `region_name`, NULL AS `channel`, NULL AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, NULL AS `region_name_baseline`, 4 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-03' AS `date`, 2 AS `region_number`, 'Control' AS `region_name`, NULL AS `channel`, NULL AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, NULL AS `region_name_baseline`, 4 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-04' AS `date`, 2 AS `region_number`, 'Control' AS `region_name`, NULL AS `channel`, NULL AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, NULL AS `region_name_baseline`, 3 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-05' AS `date`, 2 AS `region_number`, 'Control' AS `region_name`, NULL AS `channel`, NULL AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, NULL AS `region_name_baseline`, 3 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-06' AS `date`, 2 AS `region_number`, 'Control' AS `region_name`, NULL AS `channel`, NULL AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, NULL AS `region_name_baseline`, 2 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-04' AS `date`, 3 AS `region_number`, 'TikTok' AS `region_name`, 'paid_social' AS `channel`, 'tiktok' AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, 'Control' AS `region_name_baseline`, 30 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-05' AS `date`, 3 AS `region_number`, 'TikTok' AS `region_name`, 'paid_social' AS `channel`, 'tiktok' AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, 'Control' AS `region_name_baseline`, 32 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-06' AS `date`, 3 AS `region_number`, 'TikTok' AS `region_name`, 'paid_social' AS `channel`, 'tiktok' AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, 'Control' AS `region_name_baseline`, 27 AS `conversions`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '2024-06-10' AS `date`, 1 AS `region_number`, 'ITVX + TikTok + Meta' AS `region_name`, 'paid_social' AS `channel`, 'meta' AS `subchannel`, NULL AS `activity_type`, 'ITVX + TikTok' AS `region_name_baseline`, 30 AS `conversions`
),

-- For non-control region classifications, during recursion, we will need both the original data as well as the joined/exploded version so we create a copy here in preparation
`cte_data` AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    TRUE AS `original`
  FROM `data`

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    *,
    FALSE AS `original`
  FROM `data`
  WHERE `region_name_baseline` IS NOT NULL
),

-- Recursive CTEs are not allowed to perform any aggregation, analytic functions or subqueries - therefore, it will create recursive row explosion
`cte_parent_recursive` AS (
  SELECT
    `date`,
    CAST(NULL AS STRING) AS `parent_date`,
    `region_number`,
    NULL AS `parent_region_number`,
    `region_name`,
    `channel`,
    `subchannel`,
    `activity_type`,
    `region_name_baseline`,
    `conversions`,
    NULL AS `parent_conversions`,
    TRUE AS `leaf`,
    0 AS `depth`
  FROM `cte_data`
  WHERE `region_name_baseline` IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  -- The main nuance here is about passing through parent's ancestors information vs just the parent's
  SELECT
    `cte_data`.`date`,
    IF(`cte_data`.`original`, `cte_parent_recursive`.`date`, COALESCE(`cte_parent_recursive`.`parent_date`, `cte_parent_recursive`.`date`)) AS `parent_date`,
    `cte_data`.`region_number`,
    IF(`cte_data`.`original`, `cte_parent_recursive`.`region_number`, COALESCE(`cte_parent_recursive`.`parent_region_number`, `cte_parent_recursive`.`region_number`)) AS `parent_region_number`,
    `cte_data`.`region_name`,
    IF(`cte_data`.`original`, `cte_data`.`channel`, `cte_parent_recursive`.`channel`) AS `channel`,
    IF(`cte_data`.`original`, `cte_data`.`subchannel`, `cte_parent_recursive`.`subchannel`) AS `subchannel`,
    IF(`cte_data`.`original`, `cte_data`.`activity_type`, `cte_parent_recursive`.`activity_type`) AS `activity_type`,
    IF(`cte_data`.`original`, `cte_data`.`region_name_baseline`, `cte_parent_recursive`.`region_name_baseline`) AS `region_name_baseline`,
    `cte_data`.`conversions`,
    IF(`cte_data`.`original`, `cte_parent_recursive`.`conversions`, COALESCE(`cte_parent_recursive`.`parent_conversions`, `cte_parent_recursive`.`conversions`)) AS `parent_conversions`,
    `cte_data`.`original` AS `leaf`,
    IF(`cte_data`.`original`, `cte_parent_recursive`.`depth` + 1, `cte_parent_recursive`.`depth`) AS `depth`
  FROM `cte_data`
  JOIN `cte_parent_recursive`  -- deliberate row explosion (join each row to all historic data based on region_name_baseline)
    ON `cte_data`.`region_name_baseline` = `cte_parent_recursive`.`region_name`
    AND `cte_data`.`date` > `cte_parent_recursive`.`date`
  WHERE `cte_parent_recursive`.`region_name_baseline` IS NOT NULL OR `cte_data`.`original`  -- without this, we'd have duplicated rows at the root level for each iteration
),

-- Remove the row-explosion and additionally, filter out other regions where a baseline is available within-region
`cte_deduplicated` AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM `cte_parent_recursive`
  QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY `region_number`, `region_name_baseline`, `date` ORDER BY `parent_region_number` = `region_number` DESC) = 1
),

-- Aggregate away parent_region_number by taking an average per parent_date
`cte_average_daily_baseline` AS (
  SELECT
    `date`,
    `parent_date`,
    `region_number`,
    `region_name`,
    `channel`,
    `subchannel`,
    `activity_type`,
    `region_name_baseline`,
    ANY_VALUE(`conversions`) AS `conversions`,
    AVG(`parent_conversions`) AS `parent_conversions`,
    `leaf`,
    MAX(`depth`) AS `depth`  -- thanks to row explosion during recursion, we could have ambiguous values from depth 2 onwards - it's safe to take the max
  FROM `cte_deduplicated`
  GROUP BY
    `date`,
    `parent_date`,
    `region_number`,
    `region_name`,
    `channel`,
    `subchannel`,
    `activity_type`,
    `region_name_baseline`,
    `leaf`
),

-- Finally aggregate away parent_date by taking an average across all parent_date values
`cte_average_baseline` AS (
  SELECT
    `date`,
    `region_number`,
    `region_name`,
    `channel`,
    `subchannel`,
    `activity_type`,
    `region_name_baseline`,
    ANY_VALUE(`conversions`) AS `conversions`,
    AVG(`parent_conversions`) AS `average_baseline_conversions`,
    `leaf`,
    `depth`
  FROM `cte_average_daily_baseline`
  GROUP BY
    `date`,
    `region_number`,
    `region_name`,
    `channel`,
    `subchannel`,
    `activity_type`,
    `region_name_baseline`,
    `leaf`,
    `depth`
),

-- For non-leaf rows, incremental conversions must be reverse-calculated from leaf
`cte_incremental_recursive` AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      `conversions` - `average_baseline_conversions` AS `incremental_conversions`
    FROM `cte_average_baseline`
    WHERE `leaf`

    UNION ALL

    -- Don't allow negative incremental conversions at non-leaf level
    SELECT
      `cte_average_baseline`.*,
      GREATEST(0, `cte_incremental_recursive`.`average_baseline_conversions` - `cte_average_baseline`.`average_baseline_conversions`) AS `incremental_conversions`
    FROM `cte_average_baseline`
    JOIN `cte_incremental_recursive`
      ON `cte_average_baseline`.`region_number` = `cte_incremental_recursive`.`region_number`
      AND `cte_average_baseline`.`date` = `cte_incremental_recursive`.`date`
      AND `cte_average_baseline`.`depth` + 1 = `cte_incremental_recursive`.`depth`
)

SELECT * EXCEPT (`depth`, `leaf`, `region_name_baseline`)
FROM `cte_incremental_recursive`
ORDER BY `region_number`, `region_name`, `region_name_baseline`, `date`

Output:

Updated Test Expectations:

If anyone has any ideas on how to improve this or if this helps you and you want to talk it through, I'd be willing to - it's been a pretty tough nut to crack so if someone else can benefit, great.
